OpenTelemetry Collector v0.109.0 Memory Spike & Undefined Exporters Dropping Logs Behind NGINX Ingress
I'm encountering a significant memory usage issue after upgrading our OpenTelemetry Collector from v0.94.0 to v0.109.0. The collector is deployed as a Kubernetes deployment behind an NGINX ingress. Within five minutes of deployment, the pod's memory usage spikes to 80% of its available memory and remains at that level without decreasing.
Key Observations:
High Memory Usage:
Memory usage spikes to 80% within five minutes and does not decrease.
The memory_limiter processor is configured with limit_percentage: 100, but GOMEMLIMIT remains at 80%.
Undefined Exporters Dropping Logs:
Metrics for failed log records (otelcol_exporter_send_failed_log_records{}) show two exporters:
{exporter="otlphttp"}
{exporter="otlp"}
These exporters are not defined in our configuration but are continuously dropping logs.
Recurring Logs:
2024/09/22 22:30:19 http: superfluous response.WriteHeader call from go.opentelemetry.io/contrib/instrumentation/net/http/otelhttp/internal/request.(*RespWriterWrapper).writeHeader (resp_writer_wrapper.go:78)

Environment:
Kubernetes Cluster: v1.28
Ingress Controller: NGINX
OpenTelemetry Collector Version: v0.109.0 running as deployment
Previous Version: v0.94.0
